# Python Package Level Global Variable

Tags: python, global

I have following package structure. `start.py` is where user begin, and it will open a python interactive prompt.  My goal is to make all `objects` created from different function calls in `start.py` to be available in `namespace` called `vars` which can be `tab completed` in python prompt. It works if I uncomment `vars = global()` in `start.py` but can’t find the objects created in other modules

```
MyPackage
   __init__.py
   start.py
   tree.py
```

### **init**.py

```
vars = globals()              # I thought declaring vars will make it avaible for all modules
```

### start.py

```
import rlcompleter
import readline
import code 

from tree import Tree
#vars = globals()                #Un-comment this line and vars can be recognized in start 
vars.update(locals())

class root:
    pass

root = root()

A = Tree()

readline.set_completer(rlcompleter.Completer(vars).complete)
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
code.InteractiveConsole(vars).interact(banner="",exitmsg="Good Bye!")
```

### tree.py:

```
class Tree:
    B = 2
    #vars = globals()          #Uncommenting helps to get but I want vars shared between all module               
    vars.update(locals())
```

Comment: You can't share names across modules like this. The only *truly* global namespace is the built-in namespace. All other "global" namespaces are tied to a specific module. `MyPackage` is a package module that contains `start` and `tree`, but there is no other relationship between the three. Any module that wants to use a `MyPackage` global has to explicitly import it.

Comment: Also, you probably can't expect dynamic updates to various namespaces like that to allow for code completion.

Comment: If you uncomment that line, `vars.update` would throw a `TypeError`

Answer (score -1):

I had to add `from __init__ import vars` in both modules to resolve the issue.

Comment: Don't import from `__init__` directly; import from `MyPackage`, or use a relative import like `from . import vars`. (`MyPackage` is the module defined by `MyPackage/__init__.py`.)